# CMD command netsh wlan export profile folder=c:\ key=clear rseulting in: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: windows, cmd, netsh

I am trying to create XML files for each of the wireless networks on my computer, containing their passwords, in a general solution (without knowing the exact names of each network) as shown here: [Netsh WLAN Commands for Windows 10 – Here’s a Full Tutorial!](https://www.webservertalk.com/netsh-wlan-commands) in the "Export and Import Wireless Profile" section.

Using the command they suggest (which I've seen in other places as well)

```
netsh wlan export profile folder=c:\ key=clear
```

I receive the following error:

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

I have tried saving it to another folder, both in the C and D drives and neither have worked. If I add `"name=profileName"` with the name of an existing profile it creates an XML file for that specific profile, but I want to create XML files for each network considering I won't know their names.

Is there another way I can to that, or something I can do to fix what's causing this problem? Thank you in advance to any helpers, I appreciate your time!

- The cmd is already in administrator mode

Comment: Does it work with another directory thats not the root?

Comment: No, it doesn't. As stated, I have tried the D drive as well and subdirectories - everything results in the same error.

Comment: You were asked about directories which aren't root, `C:\ ` and `D:\ ` are the root `\ ` directories of drive `C:` and drive `D:` respectively. However, as the command is reportedly being 'Run as administrator', that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: The thing is, I've just tried it on my laptop and there it worked just fine... I do have windows updates pending there, I'll check if updating stops it from working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get the names of your individual profiles, you can run the command `NetSh WLAN Show Profiles`. If you do that within a [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop), you can extract the profile names and inject those into the `NetSh WLAN Export Profile Name="<ProfileName>" Key=clear Folder=C:\` command.

In [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd), *(i.e. the Command Prompt 'Run as administrator')*, the following command line may do that for you:

```py
For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims=:" %G In ('%__AppDir__%netsh.exe WLAN Show Profiles 2^> NUL ^| %__AppDir__%findstr.exe /RC:" : [^ ]"') Do @For /F "Tokens=*" %I In ("%H") Do @%__AppDir__%netsh.exe WLAN Export Profile Name="%I" Key=clear Folder=C:\
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked! I just don't understand why it wouldn't work for me with the command I've tried when it has worked for others...